# Use async in subscribe in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I have a Subject, which used to be fire async chain.

Its sometimes looks like working correctly, sometimes looks like the subscribe doesn't wait for the resolve.

```
behavior.subscribe(async (result)=> {
 await fnc1(result);
});
```

```js
fnc1(in) {
 return new Promise(async (resolve,reject) => {
  for(let w of in.split(',')) {
   await fnc2(w);
  }
  //if for finished, go to next subscribed value
  resolve();
 });
}
```

```js
fnc2(w) {
 return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  let i = 0;
  setInterval( () => {
   i = i + 1;
   if(i == 10) {
    //go next value in for loop
    resolve();
   }
  },100);
 });
}
```

Comment: Subject handling streams... 
that's means whenever the subject will receive a new stream it will invoke your subscribe...
therefore it can be that your subject will fire  <pre>fnc1()</pre> multi times.
you should harness the power of rxjs.
Try to use rxjs compositions (SwitchMap,MergeMap)

Comment: @ShaharドーンLevi Do you recommend 'concatMap' ?

Comment: pay attention that 'concatMap' will not fire till the previous observable will complete. So it can be a good solution. You are using async await in angular, what is your demand that you choose this pattern?